# Xcode turn off auto layout related warning in console outputs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

Xcode shows lengthy warnings to unsatisfiable auto layout constrains.So it is difficult to find other exceptions from the console among them. Is there any way to disable auto layout related warnings in Xcode?

Comment: Have you been able to find an answer to this one?

Comment: No, could not find an answer

Comment: Is there really still no answer??

Comment: This question badly needs an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable autolayout constraint error messages in debug console output in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239934/disable-autolayout-constraint-error-messages-in-debug-console-output-in-xcode)

Comment: Please check the date to see which one is the duplicate

Comment: @Makmeksam if the answer is useful please accept it

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
```

Answer (score 9):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable"];
```

Add this code inside appdelegate. This will hide constraint error messages from console

Answer (score -10):

If you programmatically create a `UIView`, there aren't any layout constraints defined. You have to add them manually. If you do have some `layoutconstraints` configured for a certain view, they can be removed like so:

```
[view removeConstraints:view.constraints]
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. A lot of people use Auto Layout now, and not having constraints is not an option.