# Disable autolayout constraint error messages in debug console output in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Is there a way to (temporarily) disable autolayout error/warning messages:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098420 H:[UIView:0x15c62c100(2)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098600 UIView:0x15c6294f0.leading == UIView:0x15c628d40.leadingMargin - 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098650 H:[UIView:0x15c6294f0]-(0)-[UIView:0x15c62b750]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700986a0 UIView:0x15c62b750.width == UIView:0x15c6294f0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700986f0 UIView:0x15c628d40.trailingMargin == UIView:0x15c62b750.trailing - 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098880 H:[UIView:0x15c6294f0]-(0)-[UIView:0x15c62c100]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700988d0 UIView:0x15c628d40.centerX == UIView:0x15c62c100.centerX + 1>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098420 H:[UIView:0x15c62c100(2)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Fixing the extra constraint is the only way to get rid of this message.

Comment: not the `ONLY` but the best way to get rid of these messages

Comment: When the al errors are caused by iOS and you can't fix that and the errors clutter up the logs.

Comment: @itsji10dra sometimes there are Table View issues that you just can't get rid of (even if your UI looks ok)

Comment: Incidentally, adding `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to my NavigationView made the autolayout messages go away for me in my iOS 15+ app.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Did some decompiling and there's actually a way:

for Swift 5

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
```

Objective-C

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable"];
```

Now you'll only get notified that "_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable is OFF".

Obligatory reminder for anyone reading this: this should be last resort, for tips on debugging and fixing constraint issues see WWDC's "Mysteries of Auto Layout" sessions: [part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=218) and [part 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=219).

Comment: Exactly - the need for me was to disable the errors temporarily so I could fix something else, and then return to the auto layout nightmare later. Thanks for this!

Comment: Great answer Witold!  For those of you using Swift 3 : UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")

Comment: how and where to use that instruvtion

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro where should we run this ?

Comment: In the AppDelegate. You can do it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, for example.

Comment: Is there a way to enable that back? Setting the value to `true` doesn't work. I need that to be disabled for a short period of time

Comment: Very helpful a few years later.  It looks like Xcode 12.4 and iOS 14.3 with SwiftUI decided to become very chatty about Apple's own devs breaking constraints.

Comment: I am using this for SwiftUI, so I put it in the init() method of the iOSApp struct.

Answer (score 55):

One more option is to temporarily put `-_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable NO` (notice the dash) into `Arguments Passed On Launch` menu, under the `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... -> Run -> Arguments` tab (you can also open this menu by pressing <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>), like this:

[image]

Comment: Great. I think this is the best solution to remove unwanted logs

Comment: Actually I can't figure out what is "Target" here, so search for "Edit scheme" in drop-dow menu of App Scheme button, placed at the right of Play/Stop buttons on top of XCode

Comment: Super!!  And simple.

Comment: I like this solution best. The time I want this logging suppressed is during testing, not running, so I put that launch argument into the Test section.

Answer (score 29):

***Swift 4.0 & Swift 5.0 Solution:***

```
// Hide Autolayout Warning
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
```

**Swift 3.0 Solution:**

```
// Hide Autolayout Warning
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey:"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
```

Comment: Why add a new answer with duplication solution, when can edit an original answer.

Comment: @NikKov at that time.. I don't have access to edit that answer. As i remember.

Answer (score 9):

for anyone who is wondering how to do this macOS / osx with AppKit/Cocoa

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "NSConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "__NSConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
```

Comment: where should we run this ?

Comment: i did at app entry point. If it's an app then you can do it in applicationDidFinishLaunching in your AppDelegate

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to solve this using lldb and I found a solution:

1. Create a Symbolic Breakpoint for the Symbol
   UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints in the Module UIKit.
2. As breakpoint action add the debugger command "thread return"
3. Add a second debugger command: "c"
4. Disable "Automatically
   continue after evaluating actions"

If your App encounters a layout issue, the execution is paused. With the instruction "thread return", the UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints function which prints out the error is forced to return before the warning message is printed into the console.

With the "c" command the execution of your app is continued (Note:  "Automatically continue after evaluating actions" does somehow not work in this case)

However with these automatic actions the breakpoint is likely to behave strangely if it gets hit two times in a row which will cause your app to crash. To solve this you can remove the breakpoint actions and enter the commands manually when the debugger pauses the execution of the program.