# How to turn off XCode 9 AutoLayout Constraint warning?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I have just updated to XCode 9, and there are many "additional" warning about AutoLayout constraints that were not there before in XCode 8, such as "Trailing constraint is missing", "Leading constraint is missing", ...

Theoretically these warnings are correct, and can be fixed by adding more constraints, but sometime it's overkill to do so for all views.

Is there any way to turn off, or to customize when these warnings appear?
I only want to turn off warnings that are introduced in XCode 9 like the ones above, not all the warnings, as warnings like conflicting constraints are useful and better to be kept.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239934/disable-autolayout-constraint-error-messages-in-debug-console-output-in-xcode

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik, but that one also disable the warning of conflicting constraints, which I want to preserve as they are necessary.

Comment: Had a similar issue, suggested constraints were not working so I just downloaded Xcode beta 2 build 9B46 and updating the constraints seem to be working much better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 - Localization Issue Warning Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039846/xcode-9-localization-issue-warning-storyboard)