# SwiftUI navigationBarTitle causes console warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to hide the back button name and the solution for this are these two lines:

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
.navigationBarTitle("")
```

Everything works fine except this long console warning which makes debugging really hard as I need to scroll or filter a lot in order to see the desired output.

This line is causing it: `.navigationBarTitle("")`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Warnings:

```
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003823de0 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x11fe70c30]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x11fe6f370' ']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003823e30 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x11fe6f370' '.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x11fe6eda0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003850aa0 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x11fe70c30.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600002251500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003850af0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x11fe6eda0]-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002251420'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000383b7a0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600002251420'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x11fe58990.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003851270 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x11fe58990.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000383bb60 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002251500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x11fe58990 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003823de0 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x11fe70c30]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x11fe6f370' ']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

View:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                //
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitle("") // Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
        }
        
    }
}

struct TabViewContainerView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
            }
            .tag(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with Xcode 12.2 iOS 14. Maybe it's some other Content that's breaking the constraints

Comment: Did you try `.navigationTitle("")`? Which iOS are you using?

Comment: iOS14, no thats everything. `HomeView()` is wrapped in a `TabView()` and thats it. Same with `.navigationTitle("")`

Comment: Maybe add your other Views. With the HomeView() above, I do not get any log messages

Comment: check updated question

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with 12.3. This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316497/swiftui-navigationview-navigationbartitle-layoutconstraints-issue/65318356 suggests moving over to `.toolbar`

Comment: Well I have 12.3 so seems like its a bug then ;)