# SwiftUI Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: swiftui

I am an android developer for 6+ years but recently I started doing iOS. I picked up SwiftUI which I think it's amazing and I built some screens.

However, I am getting this error in the log and when clicking on a TextField the first time. When I do that the screen is going back to the previous screen (I am going to this screen from a `navigationLink`)

The error I encounter is this:

```
2021-01-10 12:52:58.682264+0200 appName[2025:1085202] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280e898b0 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x11d57ed20]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x11d57e3e0'Add Point']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280e89900 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x11d57e3e0'Add Point'.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x11d57e010.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280e8a440 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x11d57ed20.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x28143ed80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280e8a490 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x11d57e010]-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x28143eca0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280e436b0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x28143eca0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x11d543390.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280e8ab70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x11d543390.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280e43d40 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x28143ed80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x11d543390 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280e898b0 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x11d57ed20]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x11d57e3e0'Add Point']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

And my view is this one:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddEvent: View {
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Title", text: $title)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                    .padding(10)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("AccentColor"), lineWidth: 1))
                TextEditor(text: $details)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("AccentColor"), lineWidth: 1))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 150, alignment: .top)
                DatePicker("Date and time", selection: $dateTime)
                    .padding()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingDetail.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Pick coordonates")
                }.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(Color.secondary)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 4)
                        .padding(16)
                    AdminMapsView(isLongClickEnabled: true, hideLocationButton: false, latitude: self.$latitude, longitude: self.$longitude)
                        .padding(.top, 32)
                }
                .padding()
                Button(action: {
                    if self.latitude > 0.0 && self.longitude > 0.0 && !self.titlu.isEmpty && !self.detaliu.isEmpty {
                        databaseService.addEvent(title: self.titlu, details: self.detaliu, date: self.dateTime, lat: self.latitude, long: self.longitude)
                        self.showingAlert = true
                        self.titlu = ""
                        self.detaliu = ""
                    } else {
                        self.mandatory = true
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Add event")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(10.0)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 2.0)
                        )
                }.padding(.top, 15)
                .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Felicitări"), message: Text("Mesajul a fost adăugat cu succes."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Închidere")))
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $mandatory) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Atenție"), message: Text("Toate campurile trebuie sa fie completate."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Închidere")))
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Add Point")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct AddEvent_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddEvent()
    }
}
```

I removed some variables so the code will be less and easier to understand.

I find it very hard to debug that log, if anyone can give me some hints, I think the apple developer documentation is very ambiguous and hard to follow. Thanks!

Comment: Just ran into this problem myself. It has to be a SwiftUI bug as a brand new project with only a TextField triggers the error. However it only occurs on iPad for me. Seems to be innocuous though. Looks like the same issue as these: - [https://stackoverflow.com/q/66082340/3727786](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66082340/3727786) - [https://stackoverflow.com/q/65974942/3727786](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65974942/3727786) - [https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668821](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668821)

Comment: See here for a solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316497/swiftui-navigationview-navigationbartitle-layoutconstraints-issue/65316745](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316497/swiftui-navigationview-navigationbartitle-layoutconstraints-issue/65316745)