# SwiftUi Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints - When focus on Textfield and keyboard is opening

Tags: swiftui, uibarbuttonitem

When I open a sheet with textfield, and I focus on textfield, then keyboard appears and this message appears :

```
 2021-02-06 22:29:35.817858+0100 OrientationEPS[4026:269878] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(

    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000030b3250 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fea6492cf40.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000030fce60 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x7fea64930c50.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fea6492cf40.bottom - 6   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000030ec7d0 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x7fea64930c50]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fea6492cf40 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000030fce60 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x7fea64930c50.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fea6492cf40.bottom - 6   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
```

I don't really understand what the green part says... (NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint - NSLayoutConstraint)
Can you explain me this message ?
I can add my code, but I don't know which part I have to post...

This error message appear on all my sheets with textfield focused. (3 in my app)

A ScreenShot of my app.
[image: my app]

Comment: SwiftUI is known to cause fairly innocuous errors like this in the log. If you're not actually experiencing problems, I'd say it's fairly safe to ignore.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I get exactly the same issue for my search field on top of a list. This problem causes a crash when there are too many items in the list :(

Answer (score 3):

I just started noticing this after updating to 12.4 (although I might have missed it before). After much investigation, I found that I get the same messages every time a UITextField becomes active.

To confirm this, just make a simple app with only a single UITextField, and irregardless of how the constraints are set or not, the same warnings will appear.