# How do I eliminate these common Firebase warnings related to using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, navigationbar

I am using Firebase in my SwiftUI/Combine app, and I have noticed several warnings that I would like to troubleshoot. They're not breaking things, but I'd like to resolve them. I am getting these warning using Xcode 12.4 with the latest Swift Package Dependencies: GoogleUtilities 7.2.2 and and Firebase 7.7.0.

This is the first warning as it appears in the console:

```
[GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001014] App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol.
```

For reference, this is how I am configuring Firebase:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var authState = AuthState()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .environmentObject(authState)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second warning, which appears after I set a navigation bar title using the `.navigationBarTitle` modifier.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280c8cfa0 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x109219b60]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x109218760'Fullres']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280c8cff0 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x109218760'Fullres'.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x109217100.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280c8dd60 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x109219b60.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x2816bcfc0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280c8ddb0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x109217100]-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x2816bcee0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280c88f00 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x2816bcee0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x109214320.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280c8e530 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x109214320.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280c892c0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x2816bcfc0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x109214320 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280c8cfa0 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x109219b60]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x109218760'Fullres']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Has anyone attempted to resolve these warnings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first message is caused by the fact that Firebase tries to find an `AppDelegate`, but as your app follows the new SwiftUI app life cycle, it doesn't have one.

You can eliminate this warning by adding an `AppDelegate` like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate   
  @StateObject var authState = AuthState()
    
  var body: some Scene {      
    WindowGroup {
      RootView()
        .environmentObject(authState)
    }
  }
}
```

For more details, see [my article on the topic](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-new-app-lifecycle-firebase/).

As a side note, we're looking into other ways for initialising the Firebase SDK (as swizzling has its challenges) - see [this comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7473#issuecomment-775277208) on a similar GitHub issue.

As for the second warning, this is unrelated to Firebase. If your search StackOverflow, you'll find a number of other people have run into this issue as well. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65316497/281221) looks very similar and has an accepted answer that you might want to try.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm wondering: Was it your intention to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in both the SwiftUI app life cycle initializer and the `AppDelegate`, as you have done? Would including an empty AppDelegate work instead? I believe Apple has deprecated `AppDelegate` so I'm eager to use it as minimally as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Calling `FirebaseApp.configure()` in both locations was a mistake I made when copying the code. You should only call this once. If you use an AppDelegate, call `.configure` in the AppDelegate. I am not aware that Apple has officially deprecated AppDelegate. I've updated the code snippet - thanks for spotting this!