# Silence macOS Storyboard warnings in the debugger console

Tags: swift, macos, nsuserdefaults, nswindow, nstoolbar

I'm creating a custom NSToolbar, with custom display and sizing (based on your version of macOS), using Storyboards (I know, I know... sue me, but it needs to be done in Storyboards for reasons important to the client).

However, due to all of these custom properties, my console is now getting overloaded with object-clipping warnings:

```
2021-02-10 09:47:47.293075-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.293154-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.294598-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.294663-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.295465-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.295524-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.300350-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.300413-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.305839-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.305915-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.306702-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
2021-02-10 09:47:47.306761-0500 Demo[27503:2117437] [NSToolbarItem] NSToolbarItem.minSize and NSToolbarItem.maxSize methods are deprecated. Usage may result in clipping of items. It is recommended to let the system measure the item automatically using constraints.
```

I have tried implementing my own macOS-variation of the only consistent [StackOverflow solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32745157/1234120) that I've found, as well as [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4np/1226771ab0f060583aac0ac9ba8352f5) – still no dice.

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
```

Is there a macOS solution for Cocoa-based Storyboards that will allow me to silence these warnings?

Furthermore, I tried to find a list of those Apple-included UserDefaults, but have not come across any useful resources. Where are developers finding UserDefault keys such as `"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable"`?

**EDIT:** It would be preferable if there were a solution that silenced, for example, **only** object-clipping warnings or **only** warnings for this specific NSToolbar/NSWindow. I do **NOT** want to silence **all** Storyboard warnings – as this is a last resort.

Comment: Are you sure you need NSToolbarItem.minSize and maxSize? If you need them to support older versions of macOS, you can just conditionally set them only for the older version that need it